# Laravel 5.0 whereRaw concat like

Tags: laravel-5, query-builder

I am using Laravel 5.0.

I have this:

```
return User::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%?%'", ['test'])->get();
```

and it returns `[]`.

When I change it to:

```
return User::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%test%'")->get();
```

it returns an array with 3 users.

I added this before the query:

```
\DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
});
```

And I get:

```
string(73) "select * from `users` where CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%?%'"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: how many user it should return ?

Comment: I expect 3 users.  And I think I just got it...

Comment: good to know it's done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use quotes around the `?` placeholder and it shouldn't be part of a longer string.  The prepared statement surrounds the value with quotes and/or backticks.

This works:

```
return User::whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?", ['%test%'])->get();
```

Notice that the `?` is a standalone value.  The quotes will be added when the query is executed.

Comment: Man you rule!!! This works perfect for me!!! I don´t know why you didn't have any vote :(